# Apply predict() using lapply() to a list of data.frames and output a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I have two lists in R that contain multiple data.frames. One list is a training data set and another is a test data set. I would like to use the training data to train the model then create predictions for the test data. So far I can use the training list to make predictions on a single data set (survey_points is a data.frame object). This results in a list of predictions corresponding to each training data.frame in the train_list object, perfect:

```
true_preds = lapply(train_list,  function(x)  predict(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + Bath15 + Comp13 + East15 + Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4,
   data = x), survey_points)$predictions)
```

However when I try using my list of training data.frames to predict my list of test data.frames using the following code:

```
test_preds = lapply(train_list,  function(x)  predict(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + Bath15 + Comp13 + East15 + Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4,
   data = x), test_list)$predictions)
```

I get the following error and traceback:

```
 Error in data[, forest$independent.variable.names, drop = FALSE] : 


incorrect number of dimensions 
7.
predict.ranger.forest(forest, data, predict.all, num.trees, type, 
    se.method, seed, num.threads, verbose, object$inbag.counts, 
    ...) 
6.
predict(forest, data, predict.all, num.trees, type, se.method, 
    seed, num.threads, verbose, object$inbag.counts, ...) 
5.
predict.ranger(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + Bath15 + Comp13 + 
    East15 + Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4, 
    data = x), test_list) 
4.
predict(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + Bath15 + Comp13 + East15 + 
    Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4, data = x), 
    test_list) 
3.
predict(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + Bath15 + Comp13 + East15 + 
    Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4, data = x), 
    test_list) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(train_list, function(x) predict(ranger(bc_title4 ~ ACurr15 + 
    Bath15 + Comp13 + East15 + Mcur15 + Nor15 + vrm15 + Slop11 + 
    MWav13 + X1IC2CR3IS4, data = x), test_list))
```

Comment: If you're trying to loop over two lists in parallel (train_list and test_list, it looks like) then `lapply` won't do that. You'll need something like `mapply`.

Comment: @joran thanks, solved the problem!